# How to run this jquery function only on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries, web-deployment

I'm a begginer in Javascript and I kindly need your help with this Jquery script I'm working on..

I need to **make it work only on desktop** and prevent it to run in tablet/mobile.

If anyone can help me with this that will be wonderful.

```
<script>
/*Project Collection Section*/
// Page Load
$('.grid-card').eq(0).addClass('current');
$('.grid2-item').eq(0).addClass('current');
$('.grid-image').eq(0).addClass('current');

function changeFocus(trigger) {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    trigger.addClass('current');
    let myIndex = trigger.closest('.grid1-item').index();
    $('.grid2-item').eq(myIndex).addClass('current');
    $('.grid-image').eq(myIndex).addClass('current');
}

$('.grid-card').on('mouseenter', function() {
  changeFocus( $(this) );
});

$('.scroll-trigger').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    let myTrigger = $(this).closest('.grid-card');
    changeFocus( myTrigger );
  } else {
        // do something else
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
 <script>
  var isDesktop = true;
  if (
    /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(
      navigator.userAgent
    ) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
      navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4)
    )
  ) {
    isDesktop = false;
  }
  if (isDesktop) {
    /*Project Collection Section*/
    // Page Load
    $(".grid-card").eq(0).addClass("current");
    $(".grid2-item").eq(0).addClass("current");
    $(".grid-image").eq(0).addClass("current");

    function changeFocus(trigger) {
      $(".current").removeClass("current");
      trigger.addClass("current");
      let myIndex = trigger.closest(".grid1-item").index();
      $(".grid2-item").eq(myIndex).addClass("current");
      $(".grid-image").eq(myIndex).addClass("current");
    }

    $(".grid-card").on("mouseenter", function () {
      changeFocus($(this));
    });

    $(".scroll-trigger").on("inview", function (event, isInView) {
      if (isInView) {
        let myTrigger = $(this).closest(".grid-card");
        changeFocus(myTrigger);
      } else {
        // do something else
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks smabrar for your precious time and help. Anyway I pasted the code you give me but the function does already fire on mobile devices. I'm developing through webflow, don't know if this is relevant...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake Gabriele. I modified the code to include all possible cases, it should now meet the requirements, please check.

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot smabrar you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write a javascript function that returns whether the user is on a desktop device or not from the user agent.

you can do something like this

```
function isDesktop() {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent;
  return !/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobi))|(Mobile|Android|iP(hone|od)|IEMobile|BlackBerry|Kindle|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Opera M(obi|ini))/.test(
    ua
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kays for your precious help and time. Can you guide me better on the implementation of this? It would be fantastic